# Getting this error when I am trying to install LocalStack on windows

Tags: python, pip, localstack

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\RAJCHA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ln0ptb51\\localstack\\localstack/ext/java/:tmp:foo.yml'
```

Prior to this, I had tried installing it with pip (5.9). Local stack got downloaded but could not run it using `localstack stack` , it gave `'localstack' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`

Then I updated pip to the latest version and I got this error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug in `localstack`: https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/786

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I added the path but still the problem persisted. So I started afresh.
(I am on Windows 10)

Following is what I did

1. Downloaded the respective binary for my architecture directly from https://docs.localstack.cloud/getting-started/installation/
2. Extracted the file
3. After extraction, moved to the directory.
   The problem is, If I just run **localstack --version** from the directory, I got an error saying
   *"localstack : The term 'localstack' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."*

this was because localstack command is not found in my system's PATH, and I was running it from a directory where it is not recognized as an executable.

So instead , I ran the command **.\localstack --version** and this worked!

I am not sure how much this will help you.

I am just a beginner and sharing whatever has helped me to go around the problem.

Comment: You can add the `localstack` to your path. Visit the following answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9546345/10721627